# Mapserver+openlayers: displaying a shapefile with Cylindrical Equal Area (Lambert) projection

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system, mapserver

I have some shapefiles in "World Cylindrical Equal Area (Lambert) projection".
The .prj reads:

```
PROJCS["World_Cylindrical_Equal_Area",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_
1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PR
OJECTION["Cylindrical_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",
0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-160.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1
.0]]
```

In consequence, I wrote the following mapfile:

```
MAP
    NAME "mapTest"
    OUTPUTFORMAT
      NAME "png"
      DRIVER AGG/PNG
      MIMETYPE "image/png"
      IMAGEMODE RGBA
      EXTENSION "png"
      FORMATOPTION "GAMMA=0.75"
      TRANSPARENT ON
    END
    SIZE 800 600
    EXTENT -20037507.067162 -6363885.331926 20037507.067162 6324287.725856
    UNITS meters
    SHAPEPATH "/data/"
    IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
    FONTSET "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/bruno_fontsets.list"

    WEB
      IMAGEPATH "/data/tmp/"
      IMAGEURL "/tmp/"
      METADATA
        wms_title "WMS Demo Server"
            wms_onlineresource  "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/ex/mapTest.map&"
        wms_enable_request "*"
      END # metadata
    END # web

    PROJECTION
      "proj=cea"
       "lon_0=-160"
       "lat_ts=0"
       "x_0=0"
       "y_0=0"
       "ellps=WGS84"
       "datum=WGS84"
       "units=m"
       "no_defs"
    END

    #######################"
    LAYER
      NAME "countries"
      STATUS ON
      TYPE POLYGON

      PROJECTION
        "proj=cea"
        "lon_0=-160"
        "lat_ts=0"
        "x_0=0"
        "y_0=0"
        "ellps=WGS84"
        "datum=WGS84"
        "units=m"
        "no_defs"
      END

      DATA "/data/data_repo/WRI/Base_Data/Countries/Countries"
      LABELITEM "COUNTRY"
      PROCESSING "LABEL_NO_CLIP=ON" #avoid repeating labels
      CLASS
        NAME "countries"
        STYLE 
          OUTLINECOLOR 200 200 200
          WIDTH 0.5
          ANTIALIAS true
        END # style

        LABEL
          COLOR 50 50 49
          MINFEATURESIZE 20
          MINDISTANCE 10000
          REPEATDISTANCE 0
          BUFFER 5
          SIZE 12
          FONT "Ubuntu-C"
          TYPE truetype
          POSITION auto
          PARTIALS FALSE
        END # label

      END # class
      METADATA
        wms_name "countries"
      END # metadata
    END # LAYER
    ###########################

END # MAP
```

and the following openlayers code:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/openlayers/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var map;

      function init() {
      map = new OpenLayers.Map({div:'myMap', allOverlays:true});

      var countries = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer("Countries", "/cgi-bin/mapserv?MAP=/var/www/ex/mapTest.map", {layers:'countries'});

      map.addLayers([countries]);
      var mapSwitcher = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher();
      map.zoomToMaxExtent();
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="init()">
    <div id="myMap" ></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Unfortunately, the displayed image is completely messed-up:

[image: mapserver messes-up a CEA-projected shapefile]

Can someone find what is incorrect in my codes?